# Rendering two components with Angular Routing

Tags: angular, routes, components

I am working on an **Angular 6** App, currently, and I want to change two components on a page by clicking on a certain route. Instead of creating a single component containing both, I would like to just change what actually changes (without having duplicate html tags and data).

How can I do that?

Here's some code.

**Main Component HTML**

```html
<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2 text-primary">{{title}}</h1>

    <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
      <div class="btn-group mr-2">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Esporta domanda client</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Esporta risposta server</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3">
      <div class="col-6">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <app-http-response></app-http-response>
      </div>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3">
      <div class="col-12 sm-12 md-12 xs-12 lg-12">
        <app-test-cases></app-test-cases>
      </div>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3">
      <div class="col-12 sm-12 md-12 xs-12 lg-12">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**Main Component TypeScript**

```js
export class ProcessComponent implements OnInit {
  currentRoute: string;
  title: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentRoute = CurrentRoute.getCurrentRoute(this.router);
    this.title = this.currentRoute.charAt(1).toUpperCase() +
      this.currentRoute.substring(2, this.currentRoute.length)
        .replace('-', ' ');
  }
}
```

**App.module.js**

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '', redirectTo: 'processi', pathMatch: 'full'
},
  {
    path: 'processi', component: HttpRequestProcessComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'regole', component: HttpRequestRuleComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'verifica-ordini', component: HttpRequestCheckOrderComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'prodotti-vendibili', component: HttpRequestSalableProductComponent
  }];
```

For now I am rendering just one component, but, as you can see, I want to add a further component which will be rendered on the second `<router-outlet>` tag.

Furthermore, the title is not updating properly on Route changes despite getting the `this.router.url`, but I think this is another story.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add an `outlet` property to your routes:

   `path: 'processi', component: HttpRequestProcessComponent, outlet: 'example'`
2. name your router:

   `<router-outlet name="example"></router-outlet>`

Comment: If i try then 

`{path: 'processi', component: HttpRequestProcessComponent, outlet: 'example'},
{path: 'processi', component: AnotherComponent, outlet: 'example2'}`

With the proper router-outlet it won't work.

Comment: @Teskin please share your code with both `<router-outlet>` s

Answer (score 1):

you can use, outlet feature provided by angular, below is a pseudo example based on your provided code

```
<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">

 <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
  <h1 class="h2 text-primary">{{title}}</h1>

  <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
    <div class="btn-group mr-2">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Esporta domanda client</button>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Esporta risposta server</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3">
     <div class="col-6">
       <router-outlet name="left"></router-outlet>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
       <app-http-response></app-http-response>
     </div>
     <hr/>
   </div>
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3">
     <div class="col-12 sm-12 md-12 xs-12 lg-12">
       <app-test-cases></app-test-cases>
     </div>
     <hr/>
   </div>
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3">
     <div class="col-12 sm-12 md-12 xs-12 lg-12">
       <router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</main>
```

and in routes file -

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '', redirectTo: 'processi', pathMatch: 'full',
  children: [
       { path: '', component: TeamDashboardComponent, outlet: 'left' },
       { path: '', component: ChatroomComponent, outlet: 'right' }
    ]
},
. . .
. . . .
. . . . .
}]
```

if you have any doubt in it then please let me know..

Comment: By doing as you suggests I get the following error:
{Error: Invalid configuration of route '': redirectTo and children cannot be used together
    at validateNode (router.js:567)
    at validateConfig (router.js:552)
    at Router.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Router.resetConfig (router.js:3431)
    at new Router (router.js:3363)
    at setupRouter (router.js:5012)
    at _callFactory (core.js:8242)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:8188)
    at initNgModule (core.js:8118)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (core.js:8844)
    at createNgModuleRef (core.js:8833)}